# How to theme taxonomy terms drupal 8 using taxonomy-term.html.twig

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

I need to theming all term's pages using one template for all of them. I try to do it, and create taxonomy-term.html.twig, clear cache, but it does not work. What i mast do?
Now i found this(https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217850/how-to-make-page-html-twig-based-on-vocabulary), but it is for theming each term separately. I think i need the same code but one file for all terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 uses the Views module to render taxonomy terms by default.

To get around this, simply disable the view named **Taxonomy term** (`machine name: taxonomy_term`).

Once disabled, Drupal 8 will render each taxonomy term page using `taxonomy-term.html.twig`.

Answer (score 0):

You likely put the `taxonomy-term.html.twig` file in a directory where Drupal doesn't look for it. Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/drupal-8-theme-folder-structure to learn more about allowed places.

If you enable twig debugging, you can see which file Drupal loads. You can follow this page: https://befused.com/drupal/twig-debug.
In essence, after enabling debugging, look at your site's source via your browser. Twig has added HTML comments on which files it looked for and which it loaded.

To make theming easier, I highly recommend to deactivate the render cache. From https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374:

> To disable the render cache, add the following lines to either:
>   settings.php, taking care not to add it to your production site
>   or settings.local.php, by uncommenting the lines at the bottom of your settings.php first.
>   These lines are:

```php
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Comment: Thanks. However, by default, Drupal 8 uses views (<!to render the taxonomy-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view.html.twig' -->) Can I somehow switch this to taxonomy-term.html.twig? I put this file in the theme directory and paste the code from the example here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21templates%21taxonomy-term.html.twig/8.2.x